# Akai APC20/40 MIDI Control

Tags: midi

The [AKAI APC20](http://www.akaipro.com/apc20) is a MIDI controller, which has controls that light up on it. The lights correspond to the status of a clip in Ableton, but is there any way to change these lights by issuing MIDI commands to the controller using another device (ie. my laptop)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. That is how it works. See http://www.cycling74.com/forums/topic.php?id=20355#post-106507 for basic mapping information. Basically, different velocities are for different LED colors.